# How to reward 2 answers, both right and very different, just years apart? necromancer etiquette

Tags: discussion, etiquette

What is proper zombie etiquette?

In 2014, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16199002/176818). The original answer came a hot-minute after that. In 2017, the question received a new, better answer.

What is proper etiquette so the new, better answer gets rewarded, and the original answer is still respected? Do we / Should we care?  For three years, that was the way to do it. Since 2017, not anymore.

Late 2017 and in 2018, moderators edited the "original" answer to include the "new" answer, but honestly I want to mark the 2017 necromancer answer from [XChai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2666236/xchai) as correct and let the moderator's edits go. It's a 100k view question, so I'm asking for the proper way.

Comment: set a bounty to reward an existing answer

Comment: Specifically for your question, the new answer from 2017 has 55 upvotes.  The +15 for the accept is minimal compared to the +550 rep from the upvotes so don't change just to "reward" someone = they've been rewarded plenty.  Your answer should be the best answer that helped you most.  As rene said - bounties are a more substantial way to reward answers with rep if you feel the need